# Content in between parenthesis regex

Tags: regex

I am quite new to regular expressions and may need some help.

I would like to get all expressions that are in between of parenthesis and end with a comma followed by a few digits.

for example asdasd alfalfa **(asasdasd, 2002)** asdasd fasted (asdasd) sfasadas **(asdd,2333)**

I already got the last part of this problem working by writing `,\s?\d+\)` but I am struggling to achieve a solution for the first part of my problem.

Anyone got an idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\([^,)]+, ?\d+\)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ydu5Vqy4vy1awy).

An important trick here is the closing bracket `)` in the character class `[^,)]+`, which prevents the match spanning across multiple pairs of brackets, ie matching from the opening bracket of an *earlier* bracketed term to the closing bracket of a *later* bracketed term.

If you only want the term *before* the comma (unclear because your example and your question text don't align on this point), convert the latter part of the regex to a look ahead:

```
(?<=\()[^,)]+(?=, ?\d+\))
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/0yeekVE3ljSvnN).